# The right workflow when editing class in GraphQL

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I am on xcode 11.4 and swift4, and I currently am working with AWS GraphQL and learning the proper workflow. My `amplify.xyz` config is set as

```
push=true
modelgen=true
profile=default
envName=amplify
```

So that models are generated as they are created/edited. In `schema.graphql` I define user:

```
type User @model {
    id: ID!
    firstName  : String!
    lastName   : String!
    handle     : String!
    email      : String!
}
```

And build/run the application, and am able to create/read an instance of `user` as expected. Then suppose I add a simple new field `User @model` so that I have:

```
type User @model {
    id: ID!
    firstName  : String!
    lastName   : String!
    handle     : String!
    email      : String!
    blank      : String!
}
```

And then clean the build folder, and rebuild the application. I then get the inexplicable error

```
No such module 'Amplify' HomeController.swift
```

Even though changing the `Model` class and `Amplify` appear unrelated. If I remove `blank`, and clean and rebuild, things are normal again.  What is the reason for this behavior?

For reference, here is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'alpha' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for alpha
    pod 'amplify-tools'

    pod 'Amplify'
    pod 'AWSPluginsCore'
    pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSAPIPlugin'

    pod 'AWSMobileClient', '~> 2.13.0'      # Required dependency
    pod 'AWSUserPoolsSignIn', '~> 2.13.0'

    pod 'AWSAppSync', '~> 3.1.0'
    pod 'AWSMobileClient', '~> 2.13.0'
    pod 'AWSAuthUI', '~> 2.13.0'
    pod 'AWSUserPoolsSignIn', '~> 2.13.0'

end
```

______________________ UPDATE ___________________

I an `amplify push` as Julien S suggested, and make sure all the files in `amplify/generated/models` are moved to the top level directory per (https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/start?ref=amplify-iOS-btn). Now this problem `No such module 'Amplify' HomeController.swift` is solved. However I can no longer find the data that was saved before the model was updated. For reference, when the user creates an account, I access the user's token and save it along with the user's email. Then next time the user opens the app, I get the token again and query the user db by token. Relevant code:

```
class CognitoPoolProvider : AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProviderAsync {

    func getLatestAuthToken(_ callback: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {

        AWSMobileClient.default().getTokens { (token, error) in
            if let error = error {
                callback(nil,error)
            }
            callback(token?.accessToken?.tokenString, error)
        }
    }
}
```

In MainController.swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // get user token
    let pool = CognitoPoolProvider();

    pool.getLatestAuthToken { (token, error) in

        if let error = error {

            print("error: \(error)")

        } else {
            self.getUserData(token: token!)
        }
    }
}

func getUserData(token:String){

    print("token >>>> \(token)")

   // this is successful. you got all the user stuff
   // when you change the user model, you can no longer query the user
   let _ = Amplify.API.query(from: User.self, byId: token) { (event) in
        switch event {
            case .completed(let result):
                switch result {
                    case .success(let note):
                        guard let note = note else {
                            print("API Query completed but missing user")
                            return
                        }
                        print("API Query successful, got user: \(note)")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Completed with error: \(error.errorDescription)")
                    }
            case .failed(let error):
                print("Failed with error \(error.errorDescription)")
            default:
                print("Unexpected event")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use the access token as an identifier. It changes all the time.

Comment: @Don ok thats good to know! So the question is how do I load the rest of the user's information given the token in the function `AWSMobileClient.default().getTokens` I believe the token is tied to each login session correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're configuring everything through the Amplify CLI? Are you using the new or old iOS SDK for Amazon? My workflow has generally been when adjusting my schema.graphql file to run an amplify push command to actually propagate those changes to the backend and making sure to have it generate the API.swift file. Are your graphql operations being run through the autogenerated api.swift file? You can also run amplify codegen to recreate the api.swift file as well.

Comment: so I did `amplify run` and moved over the new files in `amplify/generate/models/***` and now it builds and runs. However now I can no longer find the user on the backend even though the data is still there. This kind of make sense since the User model is new, but it creates a problem since I'll be editing the User model long after the app is pushed into production. How do I make sure the updated Model class find the right data in the db?

Comment: @Juilen S just to add to previous comment, when I create a new user and save its data under the modifed `User` model with `blank` field, I can now query the new user data with  `Amplify.API.query(from: User.self` . I just can no longer access user data under legacy model.  This would create a problem for users  in production, as I will be updating the `User` model constantly.

Comment: hmm. Your amplify commands and setup are different from what I'm used to. Maybe a new version? One thing that may be the issue, however, is that you defined `blank      : String!` but your old User in the database doesn't have the blank but you've declared it as required. If you remove the "!" from blank or maybe add something for that attribute directly in DynamoDB, maybe it will return it when queried?